# To return values for column in pandas(python) depending on the values(time) of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
Time            Shift
00:01 -6:00 First Shift
06:01 -12:00    Second Shift
12:01 -18:00    Third Shift
18:01 -24:00    Fourth Shift
```

Data is

```
DEP TIME    Shift
6:00    
7:45    
9:50    
12:05   
18:20   
21:15   
22:55   
6:00    
18:45   
21:30   

def shift (row):
   if row['DEP TIME'] >= "0:00" and row['DEP TIME'] <= "4:00":
      return 'Ist'
   if row['DEP TIME'] > "4:00"  and row['DEP TIME'] <= "8:00" :
      return '2nd'
   if row['DEP TIME'] > "8:00" and row['DEP TIME']  <= "10:01":
      return '3rd'   
   return 'Other'

df.apply (lambda row: shift (row),axis=1)
```

My observation is that if I give a value more than 10:00 in if condition it does not work. Is some value constraint with the data type?

Comment: what is the datatype of your time entries?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for bining, but first convert values [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
bins = pd.to_timedelta(df1['Time'].str.split('-').str[1].add(':00'))
bins = pd.Series(pd.Timedelta(0)).append(bins)

df['DEP TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DEP TIME'].add(':00'))
df['Shift'] = pd.cut(df['DEP TIME'], bins=bins, labels=df1['Shift'])
print (df)
  DEP TIME         Shift
0 06:00:00   First Shift
1 07:45:00  Second Shift
2 09:50:00  Second Shift
3 12:05:00   Third Shift
4 18:20:00  Fourth Shift
5 21:15:00  Fourth Shift
6 22:55:00  Fourth Shift
7 06:00:00   First Shift
8 18:45:00  Fourth Shift
9 21:30:00  Fourth Shift
```